# saving an object for an app in android, or whether that is even the right approach

Tags: java, android

So, I've got some *very* minor experience in Java, and I'm trying to learn/work on an android project. The issue I'm having is wrapping my head around saving/retrieving user data.

Its a simple marking app(its mostly for myself) but basically there is a semester object, which contains classes objects, which contains markable objects (i.e tests each with their own weightage).

So basically what I'm asking is how would I go about retrieving data.. What I really want is to display "Oh hey, this is your mark for the current semester:" when you open up the main activity/start the app (which would involve loading up the semester object which the user has entered their data into and calling up a method), but I don't know how I would open/save the objects each time the app is opened and closed.

Would I implement serialization in the semester class,  or would I save/open up the object whenever I close/open the app. Is saving the semester object even the right approach?

I've been searching for a while and I've seen questions about people opening files and I'm pretty lost right now.

(Oh and while I'm on the topic of this project, is the idea of nesting objects a bad approach? Like having a semester object which contains multiple class objects, each which contains multiple markable objects)

Answer (score 0):

> Its a simple marking app(its mostly for myself) but basically there is a semester object, which contains classes objects, which contains markable objects (i.e tests each with their own weightage).

These objects would be good candidates to store in separate tables in a SQLite database.

> but I don't know how I would open/save the objects each time the app is opened and closed.

You can extend the `Application` class and place any code in its onCreate() that you only want to run once when the app is initially started.

And in your main Activity's onCreate(), you can also place code to display data each time the user navigates to that activity.

> Would I implement serialization in the semester class, or would I save/open up the object whenever I close/open the app. Is saving the semester object even the right approach?

It sounds like your objects could benefit from storing them in a relational structure, so you might consider storing them in a SQLite database.

> (Oh and while I'm on the topic of this project, is the idea of nesting objects a bad approach? Like having a semester object which contains multiple class objects, each which contains multiple markable objects)

Not if it makes sense.  You could have for instance a Semester object that contains as a member an ArrayList of Class objects.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) can be used for object (de)serialization between Objects and a json String that can be stored in a file.

   Gson (de)serialization can also handle nested Objects as long as those Objects are serialized with Gson as well.

   Using Gson would mean though, that you will need to implement saving to a file and retrieving from it later. (Although there are numerous Android questions/answers here that should help)
2. If your objects are simple enough with just primitive data like Strings and numerical values, you could store/retrieve them in a database with Android's [SQL](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) implementation.

As for nesting objects, your scenario seems like each child and deeper descendants will be unique, so it doesn't sound like there will be any messy cases.

Answer (score 0):

Use a SQLite database to store all subjects information ie Subject object.

Implementing all database CRUD operation will solve most of your problems.

See [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

Example of adding a subject into database

```
    public void addSubject(Subject sub) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, sub.getSubjectName()); // Subject Name
        values.put(KEY_MARK, sub.getMark()); // Subject Mark
        values.put(KEY_SEMSTER, sub.getSemster()); // Semester subject is marked 

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_SUBJECT, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }
```

By using the semester key in the database , you can easily retrieving all subjects in a semester. Therefore you will only need to manage a single type of object.

This maybe a bit daunting for someone new to java but there are lots of example to start you off with and you can always find help here. Dont worry , explore.

Comment: The whole point of this project was for me to get uncomfortable and be forced to learn new things so I'll take a look at SQLite and see if I can get that working. Thank you.

Comment: Would you say it should be better to implement a SQLite database for each class, as well as each semester i.e the class database would hold the individual markable objects information, and the semester would hold the class' information.

Comment: @user3697131 Structuring and designing a a database can be very complex that in fact it is a computer science field itself. 
There are numerous way to structure the database to achieve what you want.  I will proposed that you have a single database but 2 tables.